# Benefits of stored procedures vs. other forms of grabbing data from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the pros and cons to keeping SQL in Stored Procs versus Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code)

Just curious on the advantages and disadvantages of using a stored procedure vs. other forms of getting data from a database. What is the preferred method to ensure speed, accuracy, and security (we don't want sql injections!).

(should I post this question to another stack exchange site?)

Comment: What "other forms"? As it stands, this question is too vague and open to interpretation for a good answer to be given.

Comment: still the duplicate never selected an answer

Comment: Why does acceptance mean anything? You can still learn from the answers. The asker may have disappeared or got hit by a bus, so the answers are useless forever? How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734007/when-is-it-better-to-write-ad-hoc-sql-vs-stored-procedures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934634/ad-hoc-queries-vs-stored-procedures-vs-dynamic-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462978/when-should-you-use-stored-procedures http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/stored-procedures-vs-ad-hoc-sql.html ? Anything useful there?

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer to all database questions 'it depends'. However, stored procedures definitely help in terms of speed because of plan caching (although properly parameterized SQL will benefit from that too). Accuracy is no different - an incorrect query is incorrect whether it's in a stored procedure or not. And in terms of security, they can offer a useful way of limiting access for users - seeing as you don't need to give them direct access to the underlying tables - you can just allow them to execute the stored procedures that you want. There are, however, many many questions on this topic and I'd advise you to search a bit and find out some more.

Comment: Just a note: I'm pretty sure that starting from SQL 2005, both SP's and plain SQL queries are cached. So there should no longer be any performance differences.

Comment: Plain queries are cached as long as they match *exactly*. Parameterized queries are always cached.

Comment: So SQL Server would make new execution plan and recompile: select * from foo where id = 1 and select * from foo where id = 2?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. Parameter sniffing will allow those to be picked up (sometimes). But differences like length of a string parameter (which LINQ produced quite heavily until recently) can break that. I just ran two queries and they got different plan handles. Try SELECT * 
  FROM [sys].[dm_exec_query_stats] CROSS APPLY 
       [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text]([sql_handle])
 WHERE [text] LIKE 'select * from%'

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I never tested different param length, but will keep that in mind. For the most part, I use parameterized queries and it seems to work well.

Comment: Yeah, parameterization means that the bulk of the query text matches exactly, so the plan lookup succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions on Stackoverflow about this problem.  I really don't think you'll get a "right" answer here, both can work out very well, and both can work horribly.  I think if you are using Java then the general pattern is to use an ORM framework like Hibernate/JPA.  This can be completely safe from SQL injection attacks as long as you use the framework correctly.  My experience with .Net developers is that they are more likely to use stored procedure backed persistence, but that seems to be more open than it was before.  Both NHibernate and other MS technologies seem to be gaining popularity.

My personal view is that in general an ORM will save you some time from lots of verbose coding since it can automatically generate much of the SQL you use in a typical CRUD type system.  To gain this you will likely give up a little performance and some flexibility.  If your system is low to medium volume (10's of thousands of requests per day) then an ORM will be just fine for you.  If you start getting in to the millions of requests per day then you may need something a little more bare metal like straight SQL or stored procedures.  Note than an ORM doesn't *prevent* you from going more direct to the DB, it's just not normally what you would use.

One final note, is that I think ORM persistence makes an application much more testable.  If you use stored procedures for much of your persistence then you are almost bound to start getting a bunch of business logic in these.  To test them you have to actually persist data and interact with the DB, this makes testing slow and brittle.  Using an ORM framework you can either avoid most of this testing or use an in memory DB when you really want to test persistence.

See:

- [Stored Procedures and ORM's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346601/stored-procedures-and-orms)
- [Manual DAL & BLL vs. ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904870/manual-dal-bll-vs-orm)

Answer (score 0):

This may be better on the Programmers SE, but I'll answer here.

CRUD stored procedures used to be, and sometimes still are, the best practice for data persistence and retrieval on a SQL DBMS. Every such DBMS has stored procedures, so you're practically guaranteed to be able to use this solution regardless of the coding language and DBMS, and code which uses the solution can be pointed to any DB that has the proper stored procs and it'll work with minimal code changes (there are some syntax changes required when calling SPs in different DBMSes; often these are integrated into a language's library support for accessing SPs on a particular DBMS). Perhaps the biggest advantage is centralized access to the table data; you can lock the tables themselves down like Fort Knox, and dispense access rights for the SPs as necessary to more limited user accounts.

However, they have some drawbacks. First off, SPs are difficult to TDD, because the tools don't really exist within database IDEs; you have to create tests in other code that exercise the SPs (and so the test must set up the DB with the test data that is expected). From a technical standpoint, such a test is not and cannot be a "unit test", which is a small, narrow test of a small, narrow area of functionality, *which has no side effects* (such as reading/writing to the file system). Also, SPs are one more layer that has to be changed when making a needed change to functionality. Adding a new field to a query result requires changing the table, the retrieval source code, *and the SP*. Adding a new way to search for records of a particular type requires the statement to be created and tested, then encapsulated in a SP, and the corresponding method created on the DAO.

The new best practice where available, IMO, is a library called an object-relational mapper or ORM. An ORM abstracts the actual data layer, so what you're asking for becomes the code objects themselves, and you query for them based on properties of those objects, not based on table data. These queries are almost always code-configurable, and are translated into the DBMS's flavor of SQL based on one or more "mappings" that you define between the object model and the data model (objects of type A are persisted as records in table B, where this property C is written to field D).

The advantages are more flexibility within the code actually looking for data in the form of these code objects. The criteria of a query is usually able to be customized in-code; if a new query is needed that has a different WHERE clause, you just write the query, and the ORM will translate it into the new SQL statement. Because the ORM is the only place where SQL is actually used (and most ORMs use system stored procs to execute parameterized query strings where available) injection attacks are virtually impossible. Lastly, depending on the language and the ORM, queries can be compiler-checked; in .NET, a library called Linq is available that provides a SQL-ish keyword syntax, that is then converted into method calls that are given to a "query provider" that can translate those method calls into the data store's native query language. This also allows queries to be tested in-code; you can verify that the query used will produce the desired results given an in-memory collection of objects that stands in for the actual DBMS.

The disadvantages of an ORM is that the ORM library is usually language-specific; Hibernate is available in Java, NHibernate (and L2E and L2SQL) in .NET, and a few similar libraries like Pork in PHP, but if you're coding in an older or more esoteric language there's simply nothing of the sort available. Another one is that security becomes a little trickier; most ORMs require direct access to the tables in order to query and update them. A few will tolerate being pointed to a view for retrieval and SPs for updating (allowing segregation of view/SP and table security and the ability to restrict the retrievable fields), but now you're mixing the worst of both worlds; you still have to define mappings, but now you also have code in the data layer. The easiest way to overcome this is to implement your security elsewhere; force applications to get data using a web service, which provides the data using the ORM and has specific, limited "front doors". Also, many ORMs have some performance problems when used in certain ways; most are designed to "lazy-load" data, where data is retrieved the moment it's actually needed and not before, which increases up-front performance when you don't need every record you asked for. However, when you DO need every record you asked for, this creates extra round trips. You have to structure queries in specific ways to get around this expected use-case behavior.

Which is better? You have to decide. I can tell you now that using an ORM is MUCH easier to set up and get working correctly than SPs, and it's much easier to make (and limit the scope of) changes to the schema and to queries. In the modern development house, where the priority is to make it work first, and then make it perform well and/or be secure against intrusion, that's a HUGE plus. In most cases where you think security is an issue, it really isn't, and when security really is an issue, putting the solution in the DB layer is usually the wrong place, because the DBMS is the *very last line of defense* against intrusion; if the DBMS itself has to be counted on to stop something unwanted from happening, you have failed to do so (or even encouraged it to happen) in many layers of software and firmware above it.